# Incorrect font is drawn on a PNG image while converting from SVG

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, svg, fonts

please help me with the following problem. I'm creating an SVG element which contains a bunch of text elements that looks like this:

```
<text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-13,170)rotate(0)" style="font-size: 67px; font-family: cursive; fill: rgb(140, 86, 75);">some text</text>
```

Then I'm trying to save this SVG as a PNG image using this function:

```
function saveImage(svg) {
    var link = document.createElement("a"),
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg),
        image = new Image();

    canvas.width = opts.width; // from configuration, the svg was created with these sizes too
    canvas.height = opts.height;

    image.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(window.unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg_xml)));
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    link.download = "some_name.png";
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

It works. But despite the fact that all the text elements has either "font-family: cursive;" or other fonts  - on the png it's always sans-serif. "Font-size" is ok, "fill" is ok, but "font-family" is not somehow.

Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the 'cursive' font-family is not supported in your browser?. Have you tried with another font-family, to see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for your try. But "cursive" is a generic font family so it should work everywhere. And indeed, it works fine in SVG but is replaced by "sans-serif" while converting to PNG

Comment: @SergeyChernykh  i am having the same issue plus font size is showing bigger in png? if you have solved it, can you please share answer?